# How to group and calculate average time between two columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table `tasks` like:
`id | created_on | last_modified | owner`

I want to add to my query the average time between `last_modified` and `created_on` where `last_modified` is always greater than `created_on`.

```
SELECT tasks.owner FROM tasks GROUP BY tasks.owner
```

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the avg difference in seconds you can do

```
SELECT owner, 
       avg(TIMESTAMPDIFF(second, created_on, last_modified))
FROM tasks 
GROUP BY owner
```